# Questions about assigning a probability to a randomly chosen large integer $n$ being prime

Tags: probability, analysis, reference-request, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I heard this question a few days ago, so reciting from memory:

> If I were to randomly choose an arbitrarily large positive integer $n$, could I write a function that determines the likelihood of it being prime?

Intuitively, what would it mean to assign a probability to an integer of being prime?

**Edit 1**

I'm not sure how to incorporate the [prime-counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) into this.

**Edit 2**

Alright, so the page on the [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) says that:

> Informally speaking, the prime number theorem states that if a random integer is selected in the range of zero to some large integer N, the probability that the selected integer is prime is about 1 / ln(N), where ln(N) is the natural logarithm of N.

Looking through the references, though, I can't find a more formal proof. So I will revise my question.

> For a random integer selected in the range of $0$ to some large integer $N$, prove that the probability the selected integer is prime is $\frac{1}{\ln{N}}$.

**Edit 3**

If the selected integer $n$ was prime, it's necessary that it has no prime factors $p\leq\sqrt{n}$. If we could find the probability that $n$ is divisible by $p$ as some function of $p$, then could we write$$\prod_{p=2}^{\sqrt{n}}\left(1-f(p)\right)$$where $f(p)$ is the probability that $n$ is divisible by $p$?

Comment: At the very least you would first have to define exactly what you mean by picking an integer at random.

Comment: *Is this a field of study?* See [probabilistic number theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_number_theory).

Comment: I think [this proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand's_postulate) is a rewarding one to study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Care should be taken in the sense we take the "density" of primes.

The prime number theorem states that
$$
\pi(n)=\frac{n}{\log(n)}+O\left(\frac{n}{\log(n)^2}\right)\tag{1}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\pi(n(1+\alpha))-\pi(n)
&=\frac{n(1+\alpha)}{\log(n)+\log(1+\alpha)}-\frac{n}{\log(n)}+O\left(\frac{n}{\log(n)^2}\right)\\
&=\frac{n(1+\alpha)}{\log(n)}-\frac{n}{\log(n)}+O\left(\frac{n}{\log(n)^2}\right)\\
&=\frac{\alpha n}{\log(n)}+O\left(\frac{n}{\log(n)^2}\right)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{\pi(n(1+\alpha))-\pi(n)}{\alpha n}
=\frac1{\log(n)}+O\left(\frac1{\alpha\log(n)^2}\right)\tag{3}
$$
In the sense of $(3)$, the density of primes is $\dfrac1{\log(n)}$.

Comment: A very cool solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On your second question, what it might mean to assign a probability to the likelihood of a number being prime, you might want to take a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/77177), the discussion in the comments under it, and in particular the book that I refer to there, [Towards a Philosophy of Real Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521817226) by David Corfield.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll take a day to read and understand what's going on before returning to this question.

Answer (score 1):

By the [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) it is usually accurate to assume as a heuristic that the probability that $n$ is prime is about $\frac{1}{\log{n}}$.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I should incorporate this into my question.

Comment: But you have reworded the title in such a way that the question is less answerable.  You might also like to consider the Riemann hypothesis and Cramér's conjecture.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm trying to avoid vagueness. How would you suggest I change my question?

Comment: There is no easy way to narrow it down.  I think vaguer is better.